# angularJS: order of promise

Tags: angularjs

I have two promises:

> getToken() //:get a CSFR cookie from the server

and

> getUseraData() //:get user data, but it need the cookie get from getToknen() otherwise server respond with an error.

So, I know that I can do this in my controller:

```
getToken().then(function (result) {
    getUserData(result);
});
```

But I know that it is not so good to run a promise inside a promise.

So: how can I exec the `getUserData()` promise only after that `getToken` is terminard and a value is returned?

Comment: *"But I know that it is not so good to run a promise inside a promise"* ~ got a reference to this?

Comment: If you don't want to nest the anonymous function you can do getToken().then(getUserData); I'm not too sure what you're asking about though.

Comment: why dont you use chained promises like `promise.then().then()`

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with chaining promises, which is what you are doing, as long as you don't forget to return a promise, so do it like this:

```
var getUserDataPromise = getToken().then(function (result) {
    return getUserData(result);
});
```

Or like this:

```
getToken().then(function (result) {
    return getUserData(result);
}).then(function(getUserDataPromiseResult){
    //here you will have the getUserData promise resolved
});
```

Notice that for this to work you need to `return` a promise. I insist: this is not a bad practice, this is a **[very common practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)**

Answer (score 0):

you can use deferred function.. you need to inject $q..

create a service then add your getToken http request code.. like this

```
myapp.factory('myService',$q,$http){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
        var newVal = { 'Value': val };

     var getToken = functino(){   $http({
            method: 'PATCH',
            url: baseService.getBaseService + 'ModuleAndParameters(' + ModAndParamsId + ')',
            data: newVal
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data)
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(status);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
  };

return getToken;
}
```

then in your controller,, inject the name of your service.. and just simply do it like this..

```
 myService.getToken().then(function(result){
getUserData(result);
})
```

i hope it helped..xD